# I have an array and i want to change it to a new array with last child

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

here are my array and I want to change it to a flat array with last child items i mean the deepest item (last employees in object) of array
for example in this object  "last child 3" is my answer.
{
"id": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
"name": "child 3",
"parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
"employees": [
{
"id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
"name": "last child 3",
"parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
"employees": []
}
]
},

by js code dynamically I mean items that the

> employees.length === 0

I want to put the new array to a panel and I need this new array.
I get this from API and I want to change it

```
  [
      {
        "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
        "name": "last child 3",
        "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
        "name": "child 3",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
            "name": "last child 3",
            "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
        "name": "last child4",
        "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
        "name": "last child 2",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
        "name": "bbb",
        "parentId": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
            "name": "last child4",
            "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "name": "with child",
        "parentId": "",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
            "name": "child 3",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": [
              {
                "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
                "name": "last child 3",
                "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
                "employees": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
            "name": "last child 2",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": []
          },
          {
            "id": "9ce5b48f-c978-4214-9c7e-aa34f8852457",
            "name": "last child 1",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "9ce5b48f-c978-4214-9c7e-aa34f8852457",
        "name": "last child 1",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
        "name": "aaa",
        "parentId": "",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
            "name": "bbb",
            "parentId": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
            "employees": [
              {
                "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
                "name": "last child4",
                "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
                "employees": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

** I want to change it this array with javascript code to a flat array**

```
  [
       {
         "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
         "name": "last child 3",
         "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
         "employees": []
       },{
         "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
         "name": "last child 3",
         "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
         "employees": []
       },
       
       {
         "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
         "name": "last child4",
         "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
         "employees": []
       },
      {
         "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
         "name": "last child 2",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
         "employees": []
       },{
         "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
         "name": "last child 3",
         "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
         "employees": []
       },
       {
         "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
         "name": "last child 2",
         "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
         "employees": []
       },
       {
         "id": "9ce5b48f-c978-4214-9c7e-aa34f8852457",
         "name": "last child 1",
         "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
         "employees": []
       },{
         "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
        "name": "last child4",
         "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
        "employees": []
      }
     ]
```

*thank you for your help*

Answer (score 2):

If i got you you need All object that doesn't have any `employees` in flat Array

```js
let data= [
      {
        "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
        "name": "last child 3",
        "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
        "name": "child 3",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
            "name": "last child 3",
            "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
        "name": "last child4",
        "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
        "name": "last child 2",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
        "name": "bbb",
        "parentId": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
            "name": "last child4",
            "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "name": "with child",
        "parentId": "",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
            "name": "child 3",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": [
              {
                "id": "00bba30e-788b-4c0f-812b-38dc15bfa91b",
                "name": "last child 3",
                "parentId": "089743ff-3b6b-4e99-8908-2535af8cd056",
                "employees": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "54cc976f-cfa6-4397-8c49-065001b35037",
            "name": "last child 2",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": []
          },
          {
            "id": "9ce5b48f-c978-4214-9c7e-aa34f8852457",
            "name": "last child 1",
            "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "9ce5b48f-c978-4214-9c7e-aa34f8852457",
        "name": "last child 1",
        "parentId": "67bce1a9-2354-4d0f-a788-79c9f4ac1a59",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "id": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
        "name": "aaa",
        "parentId": "",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
            "name": "bbb",
            "parentId": "bc6314fd-c2c7-4d25-94c1-f9e80ae0b44f",
            "employees": [
              {
                "id": "447b0eec-19b3-4dd9-9075-9fda9351e6d3",
                "name": "last child4",
                "parentId": "6496d673-6260-4751-b942-91b9fb1411f6",
                "employees": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
      let arr = [];
  function mapLastChild(params) {
    params.map(param => {
      if (!param.employees.length) {
        arr.push(param);
      } else {
        mapLastChild(param.employees);
      }
    });
  }
  mapLastChild(data);
  console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arr.flat(Infinity)`, look at the detailed documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: by the way thank you my frined, but i dont want that all items be flat. i want only the items that dont have any child be flat